# Sveltekit,Supabase and Vercel (problem with Supabase when deploying to Vercel)

Tags: vercel, sveltekit, supabase

I'm trying to set up Sveltekit, Supabase and Vercel.
It works correctly on a local environment (SvelteKit and Supabase), but when I deploy it to Vercel there is a problem with Supabase - "Error: supabaseUrl is required" (I post a screenshot below).
If I don't use Supabase, there are no problems with deploying to Vercel.
Please someone if you have encountered a similar one or have a suggestion to share.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I finally got this to work after doing a couple of things I pieced together from a few sources.

First, I added the the environment variables in Vercel just as the were in the .env file. For example, VITE_SUPABASE_URL and VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY along with their values.

Next, I added some code in the svelte.config.js file. The result of the file looks like this:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter(),
    vite: {
      define: {
        'process.env': process.env,
      },
    },

    // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
    target: '#svelte',
  },
}

export default config
```

I redeployed the project at Vercel, and it worked.

Comment: Just env variables in vercel works

Answer (score 1):

You should add your *Supabase URL* and *Supabase ANON KEY* to vercel and stick to the format given below `VITE_SUPABASE_URL`,`VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY` if you have initialized according to the supabase guide.

More than adding the configuration to your `svelte.config.js` file, you should emphasize on adding environment variables to your Vercel environment if you have added this file

```js
// utils/supabase.js
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
```